# FFmpeg library render text/ass subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding, subtitle

I'm trying to make FFmpeg render text/ASS subtitles into bitmap after it decodes the packets into AVSubtitle structure. In the AVSubtitle documentation there is this description:

> uint8_t* AVSubtitleRect::data[4]
>
> data+linesize for the bitmap of this subtitle.
> **Can be set for text/ass as well once they are rendered**.

However, I can't find any other information on how to enable this. Can anyone please provide a hint?

Comment: Yeah, I've just stumbled upon this problem. I realise the question was posted a few months ago, but did you make any headway?

Comment: @ZeroDefect unfortunately, I did not find an answer even after diving into FFmpeg's source code. My eventual workaround was importing libass separately and feed the decoded text subtitles into it. It's kind of silly, but on the bright side it also allows more control over the rendering result.

Comment: Hi, I stumble upon same issue, can you share the code routines for "importing libass separately and feed the decoded text subtitles" part ?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the issue with FreeType.